# HttpURLConnection sending POST to a Web Service with FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception, outputstream

I'm trying to send a registration dummy as post from  to a Web Service, to check the connection. However I'm unable to do so. The further I've been able to go can be seen below:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Log.i("tst", "Teste0");
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.connect();
        ;
        JSONObject usuario = new JSONObject();
        usuario.put("nome", "Pelé");
        usuario.put("email", "pele@uol.com.br");
        usuario.put("senha", "qwerty");
        out = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(usuario.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        InputStream conteudo = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        json = Util.toString(conteudo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

Find below Util class to obtain return from server:

```
public class Util {
    public static String toString(InputStream is) throws Exception{

        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        int v = r.read();

        while (v != -1) {
            w.write(v);
            v = r.read();
        }

        return w.toString();
    }
}
```

Find below the log from Android Monitor when trying to connect to the Web Service.

---

```
08-21 15:16:41.451 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
08-21 15:16:41.526 12155-12226/br.com.fiap.petwell D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xa09d3280 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xaea027a0
08-21 15:16:41.541 12155-12155/br.com.fiap.petwell I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1dbcd27 time:127326360
08-21 15:16:41.560 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: *URL used to connection here*
08-21 15:16:41.561 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
08-21 15:16:41.561 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at br.com.fiap.petwell.requesttask.RegisterRequestTask.doInBackground(RegisterRequestTask.java:55)
08-21 15:16:41.561 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at br.com.fiap.petwell.requesttask.RegisterRequestTask.doInBackground(RegisterRequestTask.java:20)
08-21 15:16:41.561 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-21 15:16:41.562 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-21 15:16:41.562 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
08-21 15:16:41.562 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-21 15:16:41.562 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-21 15:16:41.563 12155-12287/br.com.fiap.petwell W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-21 15:16:41.565 12155-12155/br.com.fiap.petwell I/teste: teste2
```

Execution code, as requested:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    r = new RegisterRequestTask(this);
    r.execute("Connection URL");
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: To perfect answer please provide execute code

Comment: Sorry about that, as this is just a connection test, this is called by just opening the correspondent activity:

`  @Override `
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        r = new RegisterRequestTask(this);
        r.execute("Connection URL");
    }
}

Comment: Okay! You can check your url which you passed as params[0].
Because! According to your log your url is not working :)

Comment: Actually I've tried to check that via get (browser) and via post using postman, and it worked clearly. That led me to think that's an issue on android =/

Comment: Then you can check with change you inputstream charset to ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way, using `OutputStreamWriter` over `DataOutputStream`.
The code adjusted as below:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Log.i("tst", "Teste0");
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.connect();
        JSONObject usuario = new JSONObject();
        usuario.put("nome", "Pelé");
        usuario.put("email", "pele@uol.com.br");
        usuario.put("senha", "qwerty");
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(usuario.toString());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        InputStream conteudo = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        json = Util.toString(conteudo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```